# SQL изменение значения набора полей

Tags: sql, mysql

Как можно написать такой sql-запрос, чтобы поле получило значение типа: m[i]=m[i-1]?
А также данная операция должна проходить с полями с id от 2108 до 2313.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

---

```
UPDATE Table1 T1, Table1 T2 SET
T1.m = T2.m 
WHERE 
 T1.id = T2.id+1
AND T1.id BETWEEN 2108 AND 2313
```

Примерно так, почитайте про MultiTable UPDATE MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM 'table' WHERE id>id<2314 AND ...
```

А вот дальше объясните, что за поле у ВАС...

Comment: @Эмиль Сабитов, при чём тут запрос на выборку, ведь спрашивалось об обновлении значения поля?